# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS no sound from speakers but headphone works well

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

[image: My AlsaMixer (headphones unplugged)]

[image: Volume Control detects sound is going on]

[image: Sound settings]

`uname -a` output :
Linux computer 4.15.0-42-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 19:32:57 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I also have Windows 10 installed alongside with Ubuntu. It all works well on Windows.

I don't understand how this is possible. Kindly tell me if you need any other information.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you edit your question to include the output of `uname -a` ? (Open a terminal and enter this command)

Comment: I would also recommend trying these troubleshooting steps: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure . In particular, Step 3 seems to have helped another person who has the same sound card and version of Ubuntu as you (http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/metabox-p950ep6-no-sound-in-ubuntu-lts-desktop-18-0-4-1.824939/)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I did what you suggested but nothing worked...
Here is my ALSA information http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=44feed8be9b8d70ce4dc1740f6ba1bdebf924366